# Error connecting to SQL Server Analysis Services: The '9' DIME version is not supported

Tags: sql-server, ssas, ssms

I have remote SQL Server 2016 Developer Edition installed. Trying to connect to SQL Server Analysis Services using both MS SQL Server Management Studio 2014/2016 and get error:

[image: Error screenshot]

Google doesn't help much. Found a few similar topics, but without working solution.

Client: Win10 x64 with all updates.

Need help :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case. The SSAS port was in a time_wait state (TIME_WAIT indicates that SSAS endpoint has closed the connection):

[image]

After restarting the SSAS Engine, the connection was successfully established.